# How to set zindex in konva.js?

Tags: konvajs

I have a problem with the Zindex in konva.js. After I added everything to the layer
I am trying to assign a property to a node for each element separately. But it does not work. For example

```
for(let i = 0; i<=this.layer['children']; i++){
    this.layer['children'][i].setZIndex(someInt);
}
```

How can i set zindex for all elements in layer?

Comment: Not relevant.
I thought that you could set any number in the property. But it turns out the maximum number is the number of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zIndex` in `Konva` is just index of the element in an array of children of the parent element. So you can't set any number to it and it can not be bigger than `children.length - 1`.

Comment: Just to clarify, in some dev languages like VB6 you can set z-index to any positive or negative number so I get why the OP may have thought this way. What you are saying for Konvajs is that if I have four shapes on a layer, the lowest value I can place as the value in setZindex() is 0 and the highest is 3 ?  Or is it 1 and 4 ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat from 0 to 3

Comment: Technically other numbers may work too (I mean no errors). But can give unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

If you would prefer to be able to set the render order of nodes using arbitrary numbers (like CSS, or how it works in most game engines, etc), you can use [this fork of Konva](https://github.com/SkyeBlep/konva).  Alternatively, you could also grab & apply just the rejected [pull request](https://github.com/konvajs/konva/pull/1480) for this feature if you already have a customized Konva version.

The new feature works by adding a zOrder property to all Nodes, and a special kind of group AbsoluteRenderOrderGroup that reads and understands this property for all children.

Answer (score 1):

Working snippet illustrating the getZIndex(), setZIndex(), moveUp() and moveDown() methods of the Kovajs.Shape object. See also [example at Konvajs site](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/groups_and_layers/Layering.html).

Buttons allow use to move green circle up and down the z-index list by increments of 1, then also to try to move up +10 and down -100. Resulting z-index is shown in text below circles.

```js
// Create the stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: $('#container').width(),
    height: $('#container').height()
});

// create the layer
var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var data = [ {x: 60, color: 'red'}, {x: 90, color: 'limegreen'}, {x: 120, color: 'gold'}]
var circles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1){
  // create some circles
  var circle = new Konva.Circle({
      x: data[i].x,
      y: 60,
      radius: 50,
      fill: data[i].color,
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2
  });
  layer.add(circle);
  circles.push(circle);
}

stage.add(layer);

var green = circles[1]; 
function sayIndex(){
$('#info').html("Green zIndex=" + circles[1].getZIndex());
}

$('#greenup').on('click', function(){
  green.moveUp();
  sayIndex();
  layer.draw();
})

$('#greendn').on('click', function(){
  green.moveDown();
  sayIndex();
  layer.draw();
})


$('#greenup10').on('click', function(){
  var ind = circles[1].getZIndex();
  green.setZIndex(ind + 10);
  sayIndex();
  layer.draw();
})

$('#greendn100').on('click', function(){
  var ind = circles[1].getZIndex();
  green.setZIndex(ind - 100);
  sayIndex();
  layer.draw();
})
```

```css
#container
{
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #666;
float: left;
}
#buttons
{
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #666;
float: left;
}
#info
{
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 135px;
}
p
{
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="buttons">

<p><button id='greenup'>Move Green + 1</button></p>
<p><button id='greendn'>Move Green -1</button></p>
<p><button id='greenup10'>Move Green +10</button></p>
<p><button id='greendn100'>Move Green -100</button></p>

<span id='info'></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Shape Layering Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
    #buttons {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    button {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="buttons">
      <button id="toTop">
yellow z-index -2
     </button>
      <button id="toBottom">
      yellow -9
      </button>
      <button id="up">
          yellow z-index 1
      </button>
      <button id="down">
          yellow z-index -5
      </button>
      <button id="zIndex">
          Set yellow box zIndex to 3
      </button>
  </div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: width,
      height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var offsetX = 0;
    var offsetY = 0;
    var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];
    var yellowBox = null;

    for(var n = 0; n < 6; n++) {
        // anonymous function to induce scope
        (function() {
            var i = n;
            var box = new Konva.Rect({
                x: i * 30 + 210,
                y: i * 18 + 40,
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                fill: colors[i],
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 4,
                draggable: true,
                name: colors[i]
            });

            box.on('mouseover', function() {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });
            box.on('mouseout', function() {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            });
            if(colors[i] === 'yellow') {
                yellowBox = box;
            }
            layer.add(box);
        })();
    }

    stage.add(layer);

    // add button event bindings
    document.getElementById('toTop').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yellowBox.setZIndex(-2);
        layer.draw();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('toBottom').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yellowBox.setZIndex(-9);
        layer.draw();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('up').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yellowBox.setZIndex(1);
        layer.draw();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('down').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yellowBox.setZIndex(-5);
        layer.draw();
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('zIndex').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yellowBox.setZIndex(3);
        layer.draw();
    }, false);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
Last
```

Fun messing with ZIndex code,
the `setZIndex` is all you need; It will vain the z-index inside Konva.JS